# Publish to the App Store with device in the clouds

Tags: react-native, app-store

I developed an app in React Native, rented a mac on macincloud.com and ran it in an iOS simulator on the rented machine.

When I try to send it to TestFlight in Xcode -> Product -> Archive I get the error "Failed to create provisioning profile. There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it ".

My question is: Do I really need a real physical device to test applications in TestFlight?

Answer (score 0):

select 'generic ios device' from the device list, then archive should work

[image]

Comment: It was the first thing I did, but it doesn't work. here appears "Any iOS Device (arm64, armv7)"